# django annotate a function that returns the maximum of a field among all objects that has a feature

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-annotate

Suppose that I have this model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    class_name = models.CharField()
    mark = models.IntegerField()
```

And I want to get all the students that have the highest `mark` in their class. I can get the student who has the highest `mark` in all the classes like it is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838264/django-record-with-max-element). But I want all the students that have the highest `mark` **in their class**, something like this:

```
Student.objects.annotate(
    highest_mark_in_class=Max(
        Students.objects.filter(class_name=F('class_name'))
        .filter(mark=highest_mark_in_class)
    )
)
```

I can do this with a `for` loop, but with a large database `for` loops are rather slow. I don't know if it's possible to write such a query in one line?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use 2 queries for that:

```
import operator
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Max, Q

best_marks = Student.objects.values('class_name').annotate(mark=Max('mark'))
q_object = reduce(operator.or_, (Q(**x) for x in best_marks))
queryset = Student.objects.filter(q_object)
```

First query gets a list of best mark for each class.

Second query gets all students that where mark and class matches one item of the list.

Note that if you call `.annotate(best_mark=Max('mark'))` instead of `.annotate(mark=Max('mark'))`, you will have to do some extra work to rename `best_mark` as `mark` prior to passing the dictionnary to the `Q` object. While `Q(**x)` is quite convenient.