# Django aggregation and annotation behavior comparison

Tags: python, django

I was trying to use an annotated value to filter a query set using an `F` expression, but it turns out it it does not behave the way I am expecting.

I am trying to filter objects from a query set `qs` whose property `some_prop` is the maximum of that query set. For example:

```
set(qs.values_list('some_prop', flat=True))
```

would output:

```
set([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

And I am aiming to filter `qs` by the value 9, which is the maximum. I can easily achieve that using an aggregation:

```
max_prop = qs.aggregate(max_prop=Max('some_prop'))['max_prop']
qs.filter(some_prop=max_prop)
```

But I wanted to condense this behavior in a single query, so I used an annotation instead of an aggregation:

```
qs.annotate(max_prop=Max('some_prop')).filter(some_prop=F('max_prop'))
```

However this does not show the same behavior. This is actually just filtering by all `some_prop` values rather than the maximum.

What am I missing? There must be something I am misunderstanding from the annotation and aggregation features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your annotation does not take values from a one-to-many relationship, for which the max from the set of related objects will be annotated to the object related to the set, the `Max` (for each object) is taken on only one value - `some_prop` - and attached to each object in the queryset; which isn't different from accessing/filtering-on `some_prop` directly:

> When an `annotate()` clause is specified, each object in the QuerySet
>   will be annotated with the specified values.

For a single table, you'll need to aggregate to get the max value first, then filter on that value.

Comment: so there is no way I can achieve the behavior I'm after in a single query with `annotate`?

Comment: @dabadaba There is a work around that uses `.values` to group all the objects into one and fetch the final max value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838264/django-record-with-max-element