# Django Model Query

Tags: python, django, model, django-rest-framework

I have the following 2 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Blog(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
```

How can I write a Django model query to get a list of objects which has the following formation -

```
[(user_object, number of blog posts of this user), ...]
```

This list is supposed to be in descending order. Basically, I want to obtain information about how many blog posts a user has written.

Incase, 2 users have the same number of blog posts, I want them to be sorted based on the latest timestamp of the blogpost created by them.

So, far I've tried the following and remained unsuccessful in my approaches.

```
    user = User.objects.all()
    serializer = UserSerializer(user, many=True)
    user = list(serializer.data)
    user_ranks = [(key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(user)]
    user_ranks = sorted(user_ranks, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

I do not know how to plug in the `timestamp` comparison into the above mentioned code. Also, is there a better way of achieving this?

P.S: Number of entries in `User` is same as number of entries in `Blog`

Answer (score 1):

if you set

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='bloguser')
```

You can use

```
from django.db.models import Count
some_query = User.objects.filter( ... ).annotate( foobar = count('bloguser') )
```

to attach the number of blogs, which you can then access in your template via some_query.foobar.

for the time stamp

```
some_query = User.objects.filter( ... ).annotate( foobar = count('bloguser') ).annotate( foomax = Max('bloguser__timestamp') )
```

Comment: how to deal with the `timestamp` part?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/844591/how-to-do-select-max-in-django

Comment: You can also log the latest blog post in the User model. Then you can simply .orderby()

Comment: Could you please include your complete solution in the answer above? Thanks.